# R_ from list to a dataset. How to create?

Tags: r, dataset

I'm a beginner with R statistical programming.
The highest difficulty which I found in using of R is how to correctly create a dataset in order to allow to the software to handle these data.
I'm trying to use a packge (mmSAR) which require a creation of a dataset as follow:

Creating a data set as a list of 2 elements:

```
$name : a character string specifying the name of the data set

$data : a R data.frame object with 2 columns :

    $a : a numeric vector of areas

    $s : a numeric vector of species richness
```

---

(NOTE: a and s are values which derive from my personal data)

Anyone could kindly help me to show the appropriate code for creating a dataset as required above?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: You are after a list of four elements, a vector, data.frame, vector and vector. Vectors are created using `c` and data.frames using `data.frame`. To create a list you do `xy <- list(name = x1, data = df1, a = x2, s = x3)`. This is basic R, please see [an introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do agree this is pretty basic, but since the answer in the comment isn't correct, I'll see if I can improve:

```
db.obj <- list( name = "Yournamehere",
                data = data.frame( a =c( 2000, 30000, 4000),
                                   b = c(  4,     12,   30)
                                  )
                )
```

If you had a set of named items that were values for the a and b entries you could just put their names on the RHS of the "="-signs.

It's also possible you would need to assign a class attribute to this if the functions in that package expect a particular class. Notice that after installing that package and looking at one of its examples you see this:

```
data(data.atl, package="mmSAR")
str(data.atl)

List of 2
 $ name: chr "Preston 1962 (atlantic)"
 $ data:'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ a: num [1:11] 120 150 233 304 465 ...
  ..$ s: num [1:11] 29 35 35 36 35 37 79 99 74 124 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "mmSAR.data"
```

So if you wanted to turn that object created above to resemble this example, you would need to additionally execute:

```
 class(db.obj) <- "mmSAR.data"
```